# Java project with executable jars; running and retrieving data from them

Tags: java, executable-jar, decompiling

At work, I use a Java application (I have located compiled/executable jars on the C-drive). I want to be able to grab some information from this application through code. The application itself probably does not store information, so it must communicate with legacy systems some way, I am not sure how, I have seen traces of a Servlet(?) Hence, I suspect the application also has built-in "encryption"(?)

I do not want to get involved in encryption and login procedures etc., so I am thinking I could just build a Java project around the current executable jars, and launch the application as I usually do (through the "main" entry point, "Start.jar", but then after execution call the functions that I want to (i.e. the application just runs as usual in the background)...

Would that be possible? Is there another way? Can one, for example, hook up to an already executed Java application and issue commands?

What I have tried so far

1. Downloaded Eclipse, and created a new project
2. Made Eclipse "reference" external jars (there was a wizard in Eclipse)
3. Created a new class in my new project, in which I launch the "main" entry point of the "main" executable jar (the structure of all the jars pops up with "IntelliSense"). I have also found out which argument I need to supply to the main procedure using JD-GUI (Java Decompiler)...

It seems that from inside the main procedure a call is made to another procedure, which resides in a different jar, in the debug window of Eclipse I just see an error, which made me doubt that my current approach is viable... Maybe the problem arises because the command is issued from a compiled jar? Could there be an issue with the "class path"? Does this at all seem like a solution? But then again, I have no experience with Java (mostly VBA and some C#).

Answer (score 2):

You can start your JVM for the application with options, which enable remote debugging. Then you can connect the eclipse debugger to this JVM.

http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53459.html

Comment: Hi Witek. Thanks for your answer. I actually already tried debugging. But I could not get it to work. I will have a look at the tutorial that you posted and give it another go...

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, I am going to guess that your application does not have a Java API you can code against.  That would, of course, be the easiest way. So, if you have not checked, do that first.

Assuming you don't have an API to code against, I think your approach is correct.  But it could be hard to do, since you are basically flying blind trying to figure out what the application is doing. Remote debugging might solve part of that problem.

There might be a slightly easier solution, if you are sure it is sending requests across the network.  You can use a tool like Wireshark to see what it is creating.   Then, you can have your application create requests that look like that and send them to that destination. This assumes of course that the requests aren't encrypted.  In that case you are probably out of luck.

Comment: Hi Alan. Thanks for your answer. I will definitely consider using Wireshark, I see that a portable version of Wireshark is available, which is great (user rights...)